# Is there an official API for Google calculator?

Tags: web-services, google-api, mashup

Is there an officially sanctioned API for google calculator?
[alt text http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6815/calcu.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6815/calcu.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://code.google.com/p/cl-gcalc/ there is no officially sanctioned API for google calculator and, having done some digging around, that really is the general consensus.

I found http://www.dynamicguru.com/php/currency-conversion-using-php-and-google-calculator-api/ which seems to think there is an API for Google calculator, though this just used the calculator page and things which are included on the [calculator help page](http://www.google.com/help/calculator.html)

Comment: The article you linked to does not use the calculator page, it makes requests to http://www.google.com/ig/calculator which return JSON results. I'd call that an API. However, it's not officially supported.

Comment: That API doesn't actually return JSON! :-(