# JSON returned by Google Maps Query contains encoded characters like \x26 (how to decode?)

Tags: java, json, string, google-maps, utf-8

In a Java app, i get JSON (from Google Maps) with characters like `\x26` which i want to convert to its original character `&`. As far as i can see, that's a UTF-8 notation, but i am not completely sure. In the source JSON all kinds of encoded characters can appear (e.g. `\x3c/div\x3e`). How can i decode them?

I tried:

```
String json = "\\x3c/div\\x3e";
byte [] b = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
json = new String(b,"UTF-8");
```

No luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work:

```
String json = "\\x3c/div\\x3e";        
json = URLDecoder.decode(json.replace("\\x", "%"), "UTF-8")
        .replace("\\=", "=")
        .replace("\\&", "=")
        .replace("\\?", "=");
```

The three other replaces are needed for other problems that occur with the result of a Google Maps Query JSON Result.